# Applescript - Run Multiple Instances of an App in Mac OSX

Tags: mac, applescript

I was hoping one of you kind folks could help me write a script that would open another instance of Transmission.

From my online research, I took a stab at making my own and compiled the following script for AppleScript Editor.

```
 do shell script "open -n -a '/Volumes/2 TB/App/Transmission.app'"
```

However, I get the following error message:

> There is already a copy of Transmission running. This copy cannot be
>   opened until that instance is quit.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it for other applications?

Comment: It simply will not be possible to run multiple copies of the same (Windowed) app on a single system / user account. You might be able to run multiple Transmission daemons. I'm not 100% sure if that's possible, but on Linux I run Transmission headless. To do so, they would each have to listen on different ports.

Comment: Having said that, BitTorrent is designed to max out the utilization of your connection with only a single client. Why do you want to run more than one?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to compile your own transmission-daemon to be able to run multiple instances. Once you have done this you can specify different ports on each instance and start them up.

Information on compiling your own transmission-daemon on osx can be found here:

https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=7532&p=52071

How to run multiple instances of transmission-daemon:

https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=9139